# Save a data in different variable in a list ,in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, sum

```
amount = int(input())

for i in range(amount):
    x = input().split()
    y = ([int(i) for i in x])
    z = y[0] + y[1]
    print("Result = ",z)
```

```
if i input amount = 3
and x = 2 3
        4 5
        7 8
```

Code above will print:

```
Result  = 6
Result  = 9
Result  = 15
```

But i want it to be printed like this:

```
Result = 6 9 15
```

so my idea was save each result of sum to different variable and print them, but i don't know how to do it. I f u know please tell me. Or if u have better idea.

Comment: either print without newline or store in a list and print the joined result...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking a question, try to format your code properly and structure your text well. For example, do not put some text describing your desired output inside a code snippet.

Comment: Just for fun the whole code as a one-liner: `print(f"Result = {' '.join(map(str, [sum(map(int, input().split()[:2])) for _ in range(int(input()))]))}")`

Comment: "so my idea was save each result of sum to different variable" Did you try to save each of the integers from the `x` input to a different variable? Why not? What did you do instead? Can you think of a way to apply that technique again, in order to put all the `z` values together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner solution would be to store the result z in a list and print the sums outside the loop

```
amount = int(input())
z = []
for i in range(amount):
    x = input().split()
    y = ([int(i) for i in x])
    z.append(str(y[0] + y[1]))

print("Result = ", " ".join(z))
```

Comment: But take care of the wording. You don't have an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), you have a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: at the end i use [print(i) for i in z], so the output will be in array

Answer (score 0):

change

```
print("Result = ", z)
```

to

```
print(" ", z, end="", flush=True)
```

and add a

```
print("Result =", end ="", flush=False)
```

before the for loop

you can also just leave the `flush = true` and add an empty `print()` call after the for loop.

Comment: what is syntax flush do?